# How to separately compute the Euclidean Distance in different dimension?

Tags: matlab, euclidean-distance, pdist

I got a question when using `pdist`, it would be so many thanks if you could give me some advice. The `pdist(D)` usually gives the sum of the distance for the multiple dimension, however, I want to get the distance separately. For example I have a data set `S` which is a 10*2 matrix , I am using `pdist(S(:,1))` and `pdist(S(:,2))` to get the distance separately, but this seems very inefficient when the data has many dimensions. Is there any alternative way to achieve this more efficient? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you just want the absolute difference between the individual dimensions of the points then `pdist` is overkill. You can use the following simple function

```
function d = pdist_1d(S)
    idx = nchoosek(1:size(S,1),2);
    d = abs(S(idx(:,1),:) - S(idx(:,2),:));
end
```

which returns the absolute pairwise difference between all pairs of rows in `S`.

In this case

```
dist = pdist_1d(S)
```

gives the same result as

```
dist = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(dim)pdist(S(:,dim))',1:size(S,2),'UniformOutput',false));
```

Comment: Thank you @jodag, your approach is very useful. After I got the `dist`, if I would like to compute `exp(sum(10.*dist.^2,2))`, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I doubt you'll find something faster than what you've written.

Comment: Or maybe the `bsxfun` would be faster?

Answer (score 1):

Another option, since you're simply taking the absolute difference of the coordinates, is to use `bsxfun`:

```
>> D = randi(20, 10, 2)   % generate sample data
D =

   17   12
   14   10
    8    4
    7   11
   19   13
    2   18
   11   14
    5   19
   19   12
   20    8
```

From here, we permute the data so that the coordinates (columns) extend into the 3rd dimension and the rows are in the 1st dimension for the 1st argument, and the 2nd dimension for the 2nd argument:

```
>> dist = bsxfun(@(x,y)abs(x-y), permute(D, [1 3 2]), permute(D, [3 1 2]))
dist =

ans(:,:,1) =

    0    3    9   10    2   15    6   12    2    3
    3    0    6    7    5   12    3    9    5    6
    9    6    0    1   11    6    3    3   11   12
   10    7    1    0   12    5    4    2   12   13
    2    5   11   12    0   17    8   14    0    1
   15   12    6    5   17    0    9    3   17   18
    6    3    3    4    8    9    0    6    8    9
   12    9    3    2   14    3    6    0   14   15
    2    5   11   12    0   17    8   14    0    1
    3    6   12   13    1   18    9   15    1    0

ans(:,:,2) =

    0    2    8    1    1    6    2    7    0    4
    2    0    6    1    3    8    4    9    2    2
    8    6    0    7    9   14   10   15    8    4
    1    1    7    0    2    7    3    8    1    3
    1    3    9    2    0    5    1    6    1    5
    6    8   14    7    5    0    4    1    6   10
    2    4   10    3    1    4    0    5    2    6
    7    9   15    8    6    1    5    0    7   11
    0    2    8    1    1    6    2    7    0    4
    4    2    4    3    5   10    6   11    4    0
```

This results in a 3-d symmetric matrix where

```
dist(p, q, d)
```

gives you the distance between points `p` and `q` in dimension `d` with

```
dist(p, q, d) == dist(q, p, d)
```

If you want the distances between `p` and `q` in all (or multiple) dimensions, you should use `squeeze` to put it in a vector:

```
>> squeeze(dist(3, 5, :))
ans =

   11
    9
```

Note that if you're using MATLAB 2016b or later (or Octave) you can create the same distance matrix without `bsxfun`:

```
dist = abs(permute(D, [1 3 2]) - permute(D, [3 1 2]))
```

The downside to this approach is that it creates the full symmetric matrix so you're generating each distance twice, which could potentially become a memory issue.

Comment: Thank you @beaker. This is a very good ideal, I am wondering that if there is some way existed to compute `exp(-10*dist(:,:,1).^2 - 5 *dist(:,:,2).^2)` efficiently.